# Python 3 utf8 value decode to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

Hi i am using python3 and i want to change utf8 value to string (decode)

Here is my code now

```
s1 = '\u54c7'
print(chr(ord(s1)))  # print 哇
```

It's fine if input is one char but how to change a string?

```
s2 = '\u300c\u54c7\u54c8\u54c8!!\u300d'
print(chr(ord(s2)))   # Error! I want print "「哇哈哈!!」"
```

Thanks

Edit: ================================================================

Hi all,i update the question

If i got the string is "s3" like below and i use replace to change format

but print "s3" not show "哇哈哈!!"

If i initiated s4 with \u54c7\u54c8\u54c8!!' and print s4

it's look like correct so how can i fix s3 ?

```
s3 = '&#x54c7;&#x54c8;&#x54c8;!!'
s3 = s3.replace("&#x","\\u").replace(";","") # s3 = \u54c7\u54c8\u54c8!!
s4 = '\u54c7\u54c8\u54c8!!'
print(s3)  # \u54c7\u54c8\u54c8!!
print(s4)  # 哇哈哈!!
```

Comment: If all you wanted is to print the characters properly, then why did you ask for decoding the string?...Python3 by default handles unicode chars(utf-8), so if you want to print them, just `print(s1)`

Comment: You should tell us from where you are getting such string...check my answer to see if it will help you provide us with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your `s3` string, this seems to me more like an HTML entity or text in HTML format, so use proper [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html), this way:

```
>>> s3 = '&#x54c7;&#x54c8;&#x54c8;!!'
>>> from html.parser import HTMLParser
>>> 
>>> p = HTMLParser()
>>> 
>>> p.unescape(s3)
'哇哈哈!!'
```

Or, more simply with [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/html.html#html.unescape):

```
>>> import html
>>> 
>>> html.unescape(s3)
'哇哈哈!!'
```

Quoting from Python docs on [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/html.html#html.unescape):

> `html.unescape(s)`
>
> Convert all named and numeric character references (e.g. >, >, &x3e;) in the string s to the corresponding unicode characters. 
>   ...

Answer (score 4):

If you are in fact using python3, you don't need to do anything. You can just print the string. Also you can just copy and paste the literals into a python string and it will work.

```
'「哇哈哈!!」' == '\u300c\u54c7\u54c8\u54c8!!\u300d'
```

In regards to the updated question, the difference is escaping. If you type a string literal, some sequences of characters are changed to characters that can't be easily typed or be displayed. The string is not stored as the series of characters you see but as a list of values created from characters like 'a', ';', and '\300'. Note that all of those have a len of 1 because they are all one character.

To actually convert those values you could use `eval`, the answer provided by Iron Fist, or find a library that converts the string you have. I would suggest the last since the rules surrounding such things can be complex and rarely are covered by simple replacements. I don't recognize the particular pattern of escaping, so I cannot recommend anything, sorry.